# How to reset WLAN configuration on boot on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3

Yesterday I bought a Raspberry Pi 3, and I tried to enable WLAN on it. This did not work.

Now I can't access the Raspberry Pi over SSH because it's always trying to connect to my router.

Is there a way to reset the WLAN configuration without a display?

Answer (score 0):

At the first boot after being created, Raspbian will check for two files in the boot partition.

```
ssh
```

If the file ssh is there it will enable ssh login. OBS the file is empty and has no extension.

And the file `wpa_supplicant.conf` with the content:

```
network={
    ssid="YourWiFiSSID"
    psk="YourWiFiPassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

So create a fresh Raspbian SD card and create the two files `ssh` and `wpa_supplicant.conf` with WiFi credential and of you go.